# How to control the content of include label in an XML file display and disappear?

Tags: android

I am using the follow code to control the content of include label in an XML file to display, but can't get any idea about disappear,

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/right2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        layout="@layout/detailedinfo" />
```

How to let it display and disappear?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
<include 
    android:id="@+id/right2"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

and in code use this:

```
findViewById(R.id.right2).setVisibility(View.GONE);

findViewById(R.id.right2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```